# Dijkstra python library passing value to the add_edge in Graph

Tags: python, graph, dijkstra

I am trying to use the in-build Dijkstar library from Python and have query on passing add_edge values. Please help.

```py
from dijkstar import find_path, Graph
graph = Graph()

input_file = input('Input the file name')
w = list()
i = 0
with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    for line in file:
        for word in line.split():
            w.append(word)
        graph.add_edge(w[0], w[1], w[2])
        print(w[0], w[1], w[2])
        i = 0
        w.clear()

print(find_path(graph, 1, 4))
```

The input file is following and it's working fine for w[0], w[1] and w[2]

```
1 2 1000
2 3 2000
3 4 3000
1 4 4000
```

The output is showing error as follows:

```
raise NoPathError('Could not find a path from {0} to {1}'.format(s, d))
dijkstar.algorithm.NoPathError: Could not find a path from 1 to 4
```

There is a path from 1 to 4 in two ways, then why it shows the error, not able to understand. 
It would be great if any help I can get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Believe issue was you where not converting input to numbers (i.e. weights were still strings).

Try the following.

**Code**

```
from dijkstar import find_path, Graph

input_file = input('Input the file name: ')

with open(input_file, 'r') as file:
    graph = Graph()                     # place closer to where first used
    for line in file:
      line = line.rstrip()              # remove trailing '\n'
      w = list(map(int, line.split()))  # convert line to list of ints
      graph.add_edge(w[0], w[1], w[2])  # add edge with weights
      print(w[0], w[1], w[2])

print(find_path(graph, 1, 4))
```

**Input**

*file.txt*

```
1 2 1000 
2 3 2000 
3 4 3000 
1 4 4000
```

**Output**

```
PathInfo(nodes=[1, 4], edges=[4000], costs=[4000], total
_cost=4000)
```

**Comments**

No need to declare w as a list or to clear it between usage

```
w = list()  # no need
w.clear()   # no need
```

You should almost always strip off the trailing '\n' when iterating over a file

```
 line = line.rstrip()
```

This is an inefficient way of placing elements in w

```
for word in line.split():
    w.append(word)
```

Simpler just to assign directly.

```
 w = line.split()
```

However, w would be filled with strings, so need to map to ints.

```
 w = list(map(int, line.split()))
```

Variable i is not used (or needed) so remove.

```
i = 0
```